# How do I rename a filename to a random filename in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a .php file with a random name. And I want to rename it to something another random name when a specific button was hit.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;

}

if (isset($_SESSION['submit'])) {
    rename(, generateRandomString())
}
```

I have this code here and I think that I did everything right, but I don't know how to do the rename function

Comment: The best part of PHP is that it is extensively documented. Have you tried searching for some subjective word like "rename"? http://www.php.net/rename

Comment: There is improvements that can be made to your random name string creator. Interested?

Comment: Yes I tried.. but I only found rename for images that are uploaded in that moment

Comment: Well, Why not :)

Comment: It can rename any file, as long as you have the permission.

Comment: The posted code doesn't work not because of the `generateRandomString()` function but because you omitted the first argument of [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) (the current name of the file to be renamed). In its current state the code doesn't compile and therefore it is not executed at all. The `generateRandomString()` function works fine: https://3v4l.org/Rt8Ha

Answer (score 1):

There is a [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function that does exactly what you want. Also you can use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for generating unique names for your files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to look up the rename() function in the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['submit'])) {

    $oldFileName = 'foo.txt';
    $newFileName = generateRandomString() . '.txt';

    rename($oldFileName, $newFileName);

}
```

This is it in its basic form, but in production you would want to handle errors and store the new filename etc.

Comment: But the old name is a random name, and I don't how to define it.

Comment: How do you know which file you want to rename? Is the file uploaded with a form or does it already exist in a directory or what?

Comment: Well then you know what the name of the file is if it already exists!

Comment: Nope. I have that file. At first time..yes I know its name, but when a specific button was hit, the name of it changes, and after that I would have to refresh the $oldFileName string, and that's exactly what I don't want to do. I want it to find it automatically.

Comment: I want a button that updates the file name whenever that button was hit

Comment: If you need to programatically determine the contents of a known directory you could use something like `scandir()` to loop over the files... http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php - just be wary of sub directories

Answer (score 0):

**To improve the function**.

This shuffles an array with the letters/numbers and take the ten first characters.

This should be more efficient than looping.

```
$characters = array ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
);
shuffle($characters);
return implode("", array_slice($characters, 0,10));
```

https://3v4l.org/7dUiN